# What is the geometrical difference between a line integral with respect to arc length and between a line integral with respect to a variable?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

From my understanding the geometrical interpretation of a line integral simply is the area under a curve in a multidimensional space. I think this understanding of the geometrical interpretation corresponds to the line integral with respect to arc length, is this correct? What is the geometrical interpretation of a line integral with respect to a variable? If they have the same geometrical interpretation, then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: There's a geometric interpretation that the answers there don't address. I'll try to find a better similar question.

Comment: [Tony Piccolo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/865864/26369) to "What is the difference between a line integral with respect to x or y and a Riemann integral with respect to x or y?" contains a different sort of interpretation that might help.

Comment: [bfhaha's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1374187/26369) to "Interpreting Line Integrals with respect to $x$ or $y$" has a useful picture. And [Interpretation of a line integral with respect to x or y .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1080027/26369) is another related question on MathSE (albeit with no answers)